# mySQL query using ALL keyword

Tags: mysql, database

Given this table:

```
account_number branch_name balance
A-101          Downtown        500
A-102          Perryridge      400
A-201          Brighton        900
A-215          Mianus          700
A-217          Brighton        750
A-222          Redwood         700
A-305          Round Hill      350
```

I have to find to write a mySQL query to find the branch (branch_name) with the greatest average balance. I'm trying to understand how the ALL keyword is used.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT branch_name,avg(balance) 
FROM account GROUP BY branch_name 
WHERE avg(balance) >= ALL (
SELECT avg(balance) 
FROM account GROUP BY branch_name
);
```

I'm getting a syntax error near "WHERE avg(balance) >= ALL" though.
Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error because `where` goes *before* `group by` rather than after.

To be honest, I basically never use the `all`, `some`, or `any` keywords.  I don't find that they are necessary.  If you want the branch with the highest balance, you can simply do:

```
SELECT branch_name, avg(balance) 
FROM account
GROUP BY branch_name 
ORDER BY avg(balance) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

There might be an interesting exercise in how you could do this with subqueries.  But it is more important to learn the direct approach.

Comment: Note that this works as long as there is no other branch sharing the highest average balance, [I never use SOME, ALL, ANY either - but more out of ignorance than choice!]

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Just for the record, you can replace the keywords with an aggregation in the subquery, so `x > any ()` is the same as `x > (select max() . . .)`.  I find the latter easier to follow.

Comment: Ahhh - so that's it... SELECT branch_name,AVG(balance) FROM account GROUP BY branch_name HAVING AVG(balance) >= ALL(SELECT AVG(balance) FROM account GROUP BY branch_name );

Answer (score 0):

I take it back. `ALL` is *exactly* what's needed here!!!

```
SELECT branch_name
     , AVG(balance) 
  FROM account 
 GROUP 
    BY branch_name 
HAVING AVG(balance) >= ALL(SELECT AVG(balance) 
                             FROM account 
                            GROUP 
                               BY branch_name);
```

This allows for ties!